# Nginx SSL reverse proxy doesn't work with websocket

Tags: nginx, websocket, reverse-proxy

I'm having this configuration:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl;

server_name mydomain.com;

ssl_certificate /usr/syno/etc/certificate/ReverseProxy/baac8259-962a-4d45-a265-bf747f5f007d/fullchain.pem;

ssl_certificate_key /usr/syno/etc/certificate/ReverseProxy/baac8259-962a-4d45-a265-bf747f5f007d/privkey.pem;

location / {

    proxy_connect_timeout 60;

    proxy_read_timeout 60;

    proxy_send_timeout 60;

    proxy_intercept_errors off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto            \"http\";

    proxy_set_header        X-ProxyScheme            \"http\";

    proxy_set_header        Upgrade            $http_upgrade;

    proxy_set_header        Connection            $connection_upgrade;

    proxy_set_header        Host            $http_host;

    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;

    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For            $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.4:8090;

   }
}
```

I want to apply SSL only on the frontend and use basic http in the backend.

This configuration should have worked but the websocket website won't open showing me this error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://mydomain.com:80/' failed: Error in connection establishment: 
net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Digging inside the javascript file of the web application, I see this:

```
window.websocket = (document.location.protocol == "https:") ? new WebSocket('wss://'+document.location.hostname+":"+window.jsonPort) : new WebSocket('ws://'+document.location.hostname+":"+window.jsonPort);
```

The thing is that I can really not understand why will the application detect the scheme as https? Since I explicitly try to make it appear as http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was specific to the application that I was forwarding to. I have now identified and corrected the issue in that application so this is solved.